# How to use a Django for-loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to loop over a Django array named **special_ads** in Javascript. The idea is that I can create Javascript **advert** objects and store these in a Javascript array.
These objects are used to select a certain **ad** and display additional information.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ADS = new slideshow();
  {% for ad in special_ads %}
    ADS.add_ad(new advert(
              "{{ ad.image }}",
              "Drie halen twee betalen",
              "{{ ad.company.name }}",
              "{{ ad.description }}",
              "{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ ad.image }}",
              "{% thumbnail ad.image 55x55 crop %}",
              "brown",
              "white"
            ));
  {% endfor %}
</script>


//==================================================
// ad object
//==================================================
function advert(id,title,company,description,normal_image_src,thumb_image_src,background_color,text_color) {
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
  this.company = company;
  this.description = description;
  this.normal_image_src = normal_image_src;
  this.thumb_image_src = thumb_image_src;
  this.background_color = background_color;
  this.text_color = text_color;
}
```

I can't really use a JSON list, because I also need the same array in the html at page load, as seen below.

```
{% for ad in special_ads %}
  <dd>
    <a id="std_ad_{{ i }}" class="img">
      <img id="{{ ad.image }}" class="enlarge" src="{% thumbnail ad.image 55x55 crop %}" alt="{{ ad.company.name }}" onclick="ADS.display(this)"/>
    </a>
  </dd>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that this does not work correctly. The page loads correctly, but the **adverts** are not added to the array. Also the Django part seems to execute correctly. The page source results in the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ADS = new slideshow();

    ADS.add_ad(new advert(
              "ads/logo_copy.jpg",
              "Drie halen twee betalen",
              "Directdoen.nl",
              "DirectDoen helpt u graag met schoonmaken, tuinonderhoud en klussen. Bij DirectDoen bent u voor hulp in en om uw huis aan",
              "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/ads/logo_copy.jpg",
              "",
              "brown",
              "white"
            ));

    ADS.add_ad(new advert(
              "ads/Untitled-1.jpg",
              "Drie halen twee betalen",
              "Jouwstraat.nl",
              "Jouwstraat.nl is een website waar buren &amp; straatgenoten met elkaar in contact kunnen
komen en blijven. Kijk dus snel op .
",
              "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/ads/Untitled-1.jpg",
              "",
              "brown",
              "white"
            ));

    ADS.add_ad(new advert(
              "ads/AD.JPG",
              "Drie halen twee betalen",
              "Code 06",
              "DirectDoen helpt u graag met schoonmaken, tuinonderhoud en klussen. Bij DirectDoen bent u voor hulp in en om uw huis aan
",
              "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/ads/AD.JPG",
              "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/ads/AD_JPG_55x55_crop_q95.jpg",
              "brown",
              "white"
            ));

</script>
```

I have already searched a lot, but I was unable to find a good tutorial on how to do this. Is there anyone who knows what is the best way of achieving my goal?

Comment: Why don't you want to use JSON? Just make a version of the array as JSON if you need to use your existing one as-is elsewhere in the page.

Comment: I have already tried using JSON, but it did not really work the way I needed it to work. Maybe it is indeed possible, but I am no expert at Django and JSON ;). I have it working now the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is incorrect as the Django for-loop is clearly not your problem. I guess that it has something to do with the advert or slideshow class. Does your js console not give any errors..?

Comment: Ok thank you very much :). After looking at the console I found out that Javascript was tripping over unterminated literals, caused by some endlines. It works correctly now.